# when to use "should have"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, perfect-constructions

I have a question, I have read this sentence:

> the Western powers now yielded when they should **have resisted**

but I do not understand why they use the present perfect at the end of the sentence '***have resisted***' after the auxiliary verb ***should***.

Comment: That is not a **present perfect.** The expression *"they should have resisted"* uses a non-finite perfect ***"have resisted"***, and that "have" is not tensed. The tensed verb is the verb *"should"*.

Comment: Mohammad, please allow at least a day or two before accepting an answer. For info about why this is helpful, see “[Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700)”. This question really deserves an in-depth response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/shouldhave/menu.php) is the best answer to your question:

> We can use 'should have' to talk about past events that did not happen.
>
> - I should have let her know what was happening but I forgot.
> - He should have sent everybody a reminder by email.
> - They should have remembered that their guests don't eat pork.

Comment: Good reference.  :)